# Laravel intermittent logout

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I did some research on this one and seems to be an issue for some users.

Noticed that Laravel **logs me out** automatically and intermittently. It's quite hard to replicate but it happened twice in a demo/presentation which has impact as you understand.

I can imagine that sessions can be suspect nr1 for this one but whatever I tried didn't seem to work.

How did you overcome this issue?

Comment: What session driver are you using? In my experience, the `file` driver sometimes does this if you make a bunch of requests simultaneously.

Comment: Exactly, I am using `file`- thanks, @ceejayoz.
Any other assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7549

> On rare occasions, the session file can become corrupted if one copy reads in a half written out file. This condition, however, is difficult to reproduces.

Laravel team member @GrahamCampbell:

> This is known limitation of the file based session driver.

Using a different session driver should do the trick. (My preference tends to be Redis, but the database driver may be a bit easier to set up for a demo.)

Comment: Thanks again, @ceeyayoz! I will give this a try on the next release and will come back to this thread.

Comment: @thitami You're welcome, and I hope it helps - I ran into this myself and it was quite annoying to track down.

Comment: that worked perfectly!
Thank you so much. Answer accepted!

Comment: @thitami I'm glad to hear I could save someone else the hair-pulling I went through! :-D